# How can I use angular material with angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I've tried `npm install angular-material --save` and followed [the instructions here.](https://github.com/angular/bower-material)

Then I added the script and link to `index.html`

```
<script src="node_modules/angular-material/index.js"></script>
<link ref="stylesheet" href="node_modules/angular-material/modules/angular-material.css">
```

Then I tried adding a simple `<md-button>` but am having no luck.

Comment: Check out this website https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/

Comment: yes not all the components like angular 1.x  are created using angular material for angular2 but few of them are created yet which is mentioned in the link proided by @EricMartinez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question was written, the Angular team has created the "Material Design for Angular 2" github project: https://github.com/angular/material2

See the [Getting Started](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) guide for installation instructions.

They want you to (install and) use the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

Since both projects are currently in alpha, the instructions below may change over time:

```
# install the CLI globally
npm install -g angular-cli

# create a new project
ng new my-project

# install Angular Material 2 components
npm install --save @angular2-material/{core,button,card}
```

Comment: I know this answer is a long time ago. I tried using the Angular CLI 'ng new my-project', and i see at the cmd that is installing, but it take so long to install it looks like it never ends with installing. Does somebody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is use materialize from https://materializecss.com
You just import this files into your index.html that is in src folder

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

thus you can use material design
ex:

```
 <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>Red</span>
  </label>
```